# What are the guarantees for scala access qualifiers?

Tags: scala, scala-java-interop

I have a class with this code:

```
package shop.orders.services.email

private[services] class EmailService {...}
```

Then in a different package, I use that class:

```
package shop.ui

import shop.orders.services.email.EmailService

class PaymentConfirmation extends WithFacesContext {

    var emailService: EmailService = null
```

Looking at the generated bytecode, there is no sign of any access modifier, which makes sense, as Java does not support such access restrictions.  So what happens if I create a library containing code like block one, and attempt to compile block two against the library - there is no chance that the compiler will fail, since the information is lost.  Or is it contained in something like a manifest?

I'm using Scala 2.9.2.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could reference `EmailService` from Java, but not from Scala, because Scala stores the signature of the class as a `scala.reflect.ScalaSignature` annotation. The Scala compiler will fail with the following error:

> class EmailService in package email cannot be accessed in package shop.orders.services.email

Comment: I presume its only checked at compile time and not runtime?

Comment: At runtime, you would only be subject to Java access modifier checking which in this case would always succeed, because the class is public according to the JVM.